# ListView OnItemClickListener not working within a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have reviewed the many questions about this issue, but I still haven't found a solution that works for me. I must be missing something along the way.
My `MainActivity` handles my `Fragments`. The default `Fragment` contains a `ListView` displaying nearby WIFI access points.
As with other similar questions, I don't get any response when I click on items in the `ListView`.

Here is my list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wifi_icon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_wifi"
            android:tint="@color/ws_green" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/device_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wifi_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/wifi_icon"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="00:00:00:00:00:00"
            android:textColor="@color/ws_blue"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wifi_power"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="Power goes here"
            android:textColor="@color/ws_blue"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/text_margin"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/wifi_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My list item class:

```
public class WifiItem extends RelativeLayout {

    WifiItem rootView;
    TextView lblPrimary;
    TextView lblSecondary;
    ImageView icon;

    public WifiItem(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);

    }

    public WifiItem(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
        super(context, attributeSet);
        init(context);

    }

    private void init(Context context) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rootView = (WifiItem) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_wifi, this);
        lblPrimary = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.device_id);
        lblSecondary = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wifi_power);
        icon = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wifi_icon);

    }

    public void setTvPrimaryText(String text){
        lblPrimary.setText(text);
    }

    public void setTvSecondaryText(String text){
        lblSecondary.setText(text);
    }
}
```

And the `onCreateView()` method of the `Fragment` that contains the `Listview`:

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wifi_list, container, false);

        Context context = view.getContext();
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view;
        ListView listView = (ListView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.lst_wifi_items);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Log.i("WIFI_FRAGMENT_ONCLICK", "ITEM SELECTED: " + i);
            mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(view);
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(new WifiItemListAdapter(getContext(), new ArrayList<ScanResult>()));

    return view;
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

My `WifiListAdapter`:

```
public class WifiItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    protected List<ScanResult> scanResults;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    public WifiItemListAdapter(Context context, List<ScanResult> scanResult){
        super();
        this.scanResults = scanResult;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return scanResults.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return scanResults.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_wifi, null);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wifi_icon);
            holder.tvPrimary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.device_id);
            holder.tvSecondary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wifi_power);

            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_wifi_black_24dp);
            holder.tvPrimary.setText(scanResults.get(position).SSID);
            holder.tvSecondary.setText("RSSI: " + scanResults.get(position).level + " dBm");

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.tvPrimary.setText(scanResults.get(position).SSID);
            holder.tvSecondary.setText("Power: " + scanResults.get(position).level + " dBm");

        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView tvPrimary;
        TextView tvSecondary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add any click listeners in getView method of WifiItemListAdapter ?

Comment: Why do you have `rootView.setClickable(false);` ?

Comment: Also remove the line `rootView.setClickable(false)` in `WifiItem` class

Comment: Sorry, `rootView.setClickable(false)` was on of the suggestions to try fix the issue. I have removed it,  the issue is still there.

Comment: @BatuhanCoşkun No, no click listeners added in the `getView()` method in the `WifiItemListAdapter` Just setting the image icon, and the test for the `TextViews`. I also add the views to a `ViewHolder`.

Comment: Could you post your adapter

Comment: @BatuhanCoşkun I've added  the adapter.

Comment: Try add this, listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);, in onCreateView.

Comment: @I_A_Mok Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Try to delete `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on list item RelativeLayout

Comment: @BatuhanCoşkun that was another suggestion I added to fix the issue, removing it has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in my `BroadcastReceiver`.
After scanning for WIFI networks I did this:

```
listView = new ListView(context);
container.addView(listView);
```

When I should have been doing this:

```
listView = (ListView) container.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

It seems I was creating and displaying a new `ListView` on top of the old one, but the new one didn't have any `Listeners` attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
`listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() `
```

You need to use `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` instead.

So it would be something like this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("WIFI_FRAGMENT_ONCLICK", "ITEM SELECTED: " + i);
        mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(view);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Max, I originally had `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` but it didn't work. I'll revert back to that anyway for now.